# Why is my HttpClient.SendAsync being cancelled?

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using a wrapper class I've made for HttpClient.  When I call SendAsync it throws an exception stating "A Task was cancelled".

I don't understand why this is happening, I'm not passing it a cancellation token and I'm using Await to wait for the result before returning.  Can anyone help please?

EDIT 1:  I've read there is an issue with HttpClient and Using in .NET 4.0 if not coded properly.  http://forums.asp.net/t/1863442.aspx?HttpClient+Error+A+Task+was+canceled+ .  However, I'm using .NET 4.5 and the Await keyword, so I shouldn't be having this problem.  Also when I mouse-over the HttpClient object during a breakpoint when the exception is throw it doesn't indicate the object is disposed.

Code snippet from HttpClientWrapper Class where the exception is occurring;

```
Try
  Return Await Client.SendAsync(Message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
Catch ex As Exception
  If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, Method.ToString & " " & Url & " " & ex.Message, OutputType.Error)
End Try
```

Custom HttpClientWrapper Class;

```
Public Class HttpClientWrapper
  Implements IDisposable

  Protected Handler As New HttpClientHandler
  Protected Client As HttpClient = Nothing

  Public Property OutputBufferKey As String = Nothing
  Public Property CancellationToken As CancellationToken? = Nothing

  Public Sub New(Optional Proxy As WebProxy = Nothing, Optional Cookies As CookieContainer = Nothing, Optional UserAgent As String = Nothing, _
                 Optional OutputBufferKey As String = Nothing, Optional CancellationToken As CancellationToken? = Nothing)
    Me.OutputBufferKey = OutputBufferKey
    Me.CancellationToken = CancellationToken

    If UserAgent Is Nothing Then UserAgent = RandomString(UserAgents)

    SetCookies(Cookies)
    SetProxy(Proxy)

    Handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    Client = New HttpClient(Handler, True)

    Client.Timeout = New TimeSpan(DefaultTimeout)
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5")
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1")
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", UserAgent)
  End Sub

  Public Sub New(User As User, Optional OutputBufferKey As String = Nothing, Optional CancellationToken As CancellationToken? = Nothing)
    Me.New(User.GetProxy, User.Cookies, User.UserAgent, OutputBufferKey, CancellationToken)
  End Sub

  Public Sub New(User As User, Task As Task)
    Me.New(User.GetProxy, User.Cookies, User.UserAgent, Task.OutputBufferKey, Task.CancellationToken.Token)
  End Sub

  Public Sub SetTimeout(Value As Integer)
    Client.Timeout = New TimeSpan(Value)
  End Sub

  Private Sub SetCookies(Cookies As CookieContainer)
    If Cookies Is Nothing Then
      Handler.UseCookies = False
    Else
      Handler.UseCookies = True
      Handler.CookieContainer = Cookies
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub SetProxy(Proxy As WebProxy)
    If Proxy Is Nothing Then
      Handler.UseProxy = False
    Else
      Handler.UseProxy = True
      Handler.Proxy = Proxy
    End If
  End Sub

  Public Async Function WebRequestByteAsync(Url As String, Optional RequestMethod As RequestMethod = RequestMethod.GET, Optional Content As Object = Nothing, _
                                              Optional ContentType As ContentType = ContentType.Default, Optional Accept As String = DefaultAcceptString, _
                                              Optional AdditionalHeaders As NameValueCollection = Nothing, Optional Referer As String = Nothing, Optional NoCache As Boolean = False) _
                                   As Tasks.Task(Of Byte())
    Using Response As HttpResponseMessage = Await WebRequestAsync(Url, RequestMethod, Content, ContentType, Accept, AdditionalHeaders, Referer, NoCache)
      If Response IsNot Nothing Then
        If Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
          Return Await GetResponseByteAsync(Response)
        Else
          Output(OutputBufferKey, Url & " did not return OK (200)", OutputType.Error)
        End If
      End If
      Return Nothing
    End Using
  End Function

  Public Async Function WebRequestStringAsync(Url As String, Optional RequestMethod As RequestMethod = RequestMethod.GET, Optional Content As Object = Nothing, _
                                              Optional ContentType As ContentType = ContentType.Default, Optional Accept As String = DefaultAcceptString, _
                                              Optional AdditionalHeaders As NameValueCollection = Nothing, Optional Referer As String = Nothing, Optional NoCache As Boolean = False) _
                                   As Tasks.Task(Of String)
    Using Response As HttpResponseMessage = Await WebRequestAsync(Url, RequestMethod, Content, ContentType, Accept, AdditionalHeaders, Referer, NoCache)
      If Response IsNot Nothing Then
        If Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
          Return Await GetResponseStringAsync(Response)
        Else
          Output(OutputBufferKey, Url & " did not return OK (200)", OutputType.Error)
        End If
      End If
      Return Nothing
    End Using
  End Function

  Public Async Function WebRequestAsync(Url As String, Optional RequestMethod As RequestMethod = RequestMethod.GET, Optional Content As Object = Nothing, _
                                              Optional ContentType As ContentType = ContentType.Default, Optional Accept As String = DefaultAcceptString, _
                                              Optional AdditionalHeaders As NameValueCollection = Nothing, Optional Referer As String = Nothing, Optional NoCache As Boolean = False, _
                                              Optional CanBeCancelled As Boolean = True) _
                                   As Tasks.Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)

    Dim Method As HttpMethod = Nothing
    Select Case RequestMethod
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.DELETE : Method = HttpMethod.Delete
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.GET : Method = HttpMethod.Get
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.OPTIONS : Method = HttpMethod.Options
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.POST : Method = HttpMethod.Post
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.PUT : Method = HttpMethod.Put
    End Select

    'prepare message
    Dim Message As New HttpRequestMessage(Method, Url)
    Message.Headers.ExpectContinue = False
    Message.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", Accept)
    If Referer IsNot Nothing Then Message.Headers.Add("Referer", Referer)
    If NoCache Then
      Message.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache")
      Message.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    End If
    If AdditionalHeaders IsNot Nothing Then
      For Each Key In AdditionalHeaders.AllKeys
        Message.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(Key, AdditionalHeaders(Key))
      Next
    End If

    'set content
    If Content IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim ContentTypeString As String = GetEnumDescription(ContentType)

      Dim ContentBytes As Byte() = Nothing
      If TypeOf Content Is String Then
        ContentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CType(Content, String))
      ElseIf TypeOf Content Is Byte() Then
        ContentBytes = CType(Content, Byte())
      ElseIf TypeOf Content Is MultiPartPostData Then
        Dim MultiPartPostData As MultiPartPostData = CType(Content, MultiPartPostData)
        ContentBytes = MultiPartPostData.Bytes
        ContentTypeString += "; boundary=" & MultiPartPostData.Boundary
      End If

      Dim ByteArrayContent As New ByteArrayContent(ContentBytes)
      ByteArrayContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", ContentTypeString)
      Message.Content = ByteArrayContent
    End If

    'get response
    Output(OutputBufferKey, RequestMethod.ToString & " " & Url, OutputType.Debug)

    Try
      Return Await Client.SendAsync(Message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
    Catch ex As Exception
      If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, Method.ToString & " " & Url & " " & ex.Message, OutputType.Error)
    End Try

    Return Nothing
  End Function

  Public Async Function GetResponseByteAsync(Response As HttpResponseMessage) As Tasks.Task(Of Byte())
    If Response Is Nothing Then
      If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, "Unable read content from response message: Is nothing", OutputType.Error)
    Else
      Try
        Return Await Response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync
      Catch ex As Exception
        If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, "Unable read content from " & Response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString & ": " & ex.Message, OutputType.Error)
      End Try
    End If

    Return Nothing
  End Function

  Public Async Function GetResponseStringAsync(Response As HttpResponseMessage) As Tasks.Task(Of String)
    If Response Is Nothing Then
      If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, "Unable read content from response message: Is nothing", OutputType.Error)
    Else
      Try
        Return Await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
      Catch ex As Exception
        If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, "Unable read content from " & Response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString & ": " & ex.Message, OutputType.Error)
      End Try
    End If

    Return Nothing
  End Function

#Region "IDisposable Support"
  Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

  ' IDisposable
  Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
      If disposing Then
        If Client IsNot Nothing Then Client.Dispose()
      End If

    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
  End Sub

  ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
  Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
  End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Main code;

```
Module Main

  Dim ProxyUrl As String = "proxies.txt"

  Sub main()
    DebugMode = True
    OutputToConsole = True

    Dim Proxies As New ProxyList(ProxyUrl)

    Try
      Run(Proxies).GetAwaiter.GetResult()
    Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Console.ReadLine()

  End Sub

  Public Async Function Run(Proxies As ProxyList) As Tasks.Task

    Dim Proxy As WebProxy = Await Proxies.GetProxy

    Using Client As New HttpClientWrapper(Proxy)

      Dim Response As String = Await Client.WebRequestStringAsync("http://www.google.com")
      If Response IsNot Nothing Then Console.WriteLine(Response)

    End Using

  End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTTPClient` says task has been cancelled when timeout is reached: are you sure you have large enought timeout/the web service responds in a timely fashion?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction I was setting the timeout with new TimeSpan(Ticks) with ticks being 8000.  I mistook ticks for milliseconds.  Problem solved.

Comment: cool! Just as a good idea for future - that would make a better question if you would dump exception into the question.

Comment: Appreciate the advice, but not sure what you mean.  Is there an easy way to get all details of an exception to put in the question?

Comment: just copy except.ToString() output into the question and format it as code/quote

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I was configuring the HttpClientFactory like this:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient(string.Empty, c =>
            {
               c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            })
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler((c) => new HttpClientHandler
            {                                                                   
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
            });
```

Then calling

```cs
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

It turns out changing the automatic decompression to GZip *only* fixed the issue:

```cs
AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
```

Really odd.